# How to get variant \boxtimes without long strokes

Tags: symbols

In many maths papers, I've seen a variant of \boxtimes, that looks more like the picture on the left than the standard version of \boxtimes on the right:

[image]

Previously, I've been able to get it by typing \boxtimes, but I cannot replicate it now.

**My question:** What do you do to get the one on the left to appear when you type \boxtimes?

Apologies for the short question, but I've searched pretty thoroughly and not been able to find an answer.

Comment: Please add the comment you left to my answer to your question, because it makes it a completely different question. Basically you want to ask: Which font has `\boxtimes` like in the first picture?

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for not being specific enough before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[\boxtimes\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: n.b. this does not change the font (campa's comment might imply that it does, so I'm clarifying for future readers).

Comment: @Pulcinella This changes the font of many symbols, for a full list see the package documentation

Comment: @Pulcinella It surely changes all *math* symbols, though not the text font, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

You *might* load `mathabx`, but this would change *all* math symbols.

If we look in `mathabx.dcl` we find

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxtimes}{2}{mathb}{"62}
```

where `2` means `\mathbin`, `mathb` is the symbol font's name and `"62` is the slot.

Now we look in `mathabx.sty` to see

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
```

but we can modify this to have fully scalable fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxtimes}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"62}

\begin{document}

$a\boxtimes b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also present an alternative, showing a comparison between the available symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\NewCommandCopy{\origboxtimes}{\boxtimes}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxtimes}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"62}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varboxtimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\varboxtimes@\relax}}
\newcommand{\varboxtimes@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{$#1\Box$}}$}%
  \vphantom{\usebox\z@}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1\times$\hidewidth\cr\usebox\z@\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\boxtimes b \varboxtimes c \origboxtimes d$

\end{document}
```

[image]